# Spring XD custom class type for processor input

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

I wrote a proccessor module that gets a `String` payload and return results as `LogFileTuple` type. this module works good.
I wrote another module that gets `LogFileTuple` as input. but when deploying stream as: `Source | Module1 | Module2 | Sink` get `MessageDeliveryException`.

My transfor method:

```
public Event transform(LogFileTuple payload) {
    if (payload == null) {
      return null;
    }

    try {
      Event event = logParser.parse(payload);
      if (event != null) {
        return event;
      } else {
        logger.warn("LogParser result is null: {}.", payload);
        return null;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.warn("Cannot parse logFileTuple: {}.", payload, e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

my xml config for Module2 is:

```
<int:channel id="input" datatype="com.company.threatanalyzer.core.commons.tuple.LogFileTuple"/>

<int:transformer input-channel="input" output-channel="output">
    <beans:bean class="com.company.threatanalyzer.xd.plugin.XdLogParser" />
</int:transformer>

<int:channel id="output"/>
```

I get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Channel 'input' expected one of the following datataypes [class com.company.threatanalyzer.core.commons.tuple.LogFileTuple], but received [class com.company.threatanalyzer.core.commons.tuple.LogFileTuple]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.convertPayloadIfNecessary(AbstractMessageChannel.java:499) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:426) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$400(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:45) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$1.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-integration-amqp-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757) ~[spring-rabbit-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a class loader issue; each module loaded it's own version of `LogFileTuple`. In Java, classes are scoped by the classloader that loads them so, in this case, it's a different `Class` instance.

You need to elevate the jar that contains that class to `/xd/lib` so it's loaded by a shared class loader.